# Transpose column with particular character to rows

Tags: sas, transpose

How can we transpose several variables in SAS that begin with a specific character e.g. `_` without naming each variable separately? These variables only have `_` in common and rets of the variable names are different. Once transposed, I would like to rename the column as `new_col` such that all the variables will fall into separate rows below this column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable short cut list, specifically the colon which allows you to match based on the same prefix, in this case the underscore.

Mentioning `_:` will refer to all variables that start with _. If you need to exclude any this will not work.

Comment: How to write a dummy code to transpose only those column variables to row in dataset that begin with an `_` e.g. transpose column named `_XYZ`?

Comment: Write it the way you would to list specific variables. Then instead of listing the specific variables use `_:` in place of the variable list, which will refer to all the variables. If you don't know how to do a transpose that's a different question IMO.